# pdo select and insert statement

Tags: php, sql

I hardly succeed to convert my classic db_connection to a pdo, and it seems - it works...
But have problem with two specific select and insert statement:

```
 $comments = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE page='$_SESSION[page]' ORDER BY dt ASC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $comments[] = new Comment($row);
    }
    foreach($comments as $c){
        echo $c->markup();
    }
```

And

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments(page,name,url,email,body)VALUES (
'{$_SESSION['page']}',
'".$arr['name']."',
'".$arr['url']."',
'".$arr['email']."',
'".$arr['body']."'
)");

$arr['dt'] = date('r',time());
$arr['id'] = mysql_insert_id();
```

This all works as is, but as pdo - i tried many "examples" - without result.

Comment: I think he wants us to do the heavy lifting here and convert this simple MySQL into PDO form.

Comment: Post the "examples" you have tried and we'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$comments = array();
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;",$username,$password);
$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE page='$_SESSION[page]' ORDER BY dt ASC");
$pdo->execute();
while($result = $pdo->fetch()) {
  array_push($comments,$result);
}
```

The other one should now be cake for you to convert yourself.

Comment: Thanks, L0j1k. Not sure about `cake` but I hope.. :)